# How do i get Module inside a LoopPass? I need it to do Module - getOrInsertFunction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

How do i get Module inside a LoopPass? I need it to do Module - getOrInsertFunction?

Using Loop 'L'

```
void Mypass::fillPrintfunctions(Loop *L)
{
    Module *M = L->getPreheader()->getParent()->getParent() ;
    Constant *PrintFunc;
    PrintFunc = M->getOrInsertFunction("Print", Type::getVoidTy(M->getContext()), (Type*)0);
    FPrint= cast<Function>(PrintFunc);//Fprint is Function *Fprint defined in Mypass;
}

bool Mypass:: runOnLoop(Loop *L, LPPassManager &LPM)
{
    if(!filled){         
       fillPrintfunctions(L);
    }

    return true;
 }
```

results in error: forward declaration of 'class llvm::Module'
Class Module;

Comment: Show us more code please.

Comment: Sorry My Mistake, I had included llvm/IR/Module.h but compiled an OLD file. It works without problem now.